# https Subdomain always redirects to main domain

Tags: apache-2.4

i have main domain on https ssl. but 2 sub domain on http.
like 
main domain

```
https://expamle.com
```

sub domains

```
http://s1.example.com 
http://s2.example.com
```

problem is that when open subdomain with http . its work fine, but when its open with https its show main domain but domain same. please tell me whats httaccess rules for it or apache confiq for it . i want any open sub domain open with https work fine and its auto redirect http

Comment: Since you don't include any useful configuration (snippets) it's a bit of a guess, but each Apache VirtualHost entry you have on port 80/plain http needs to be duplicated for  HTTPS on port 443.

Comment: thanks for reply . i am not understand  . whats i change , can i put something in .htaccess because its very easy for me

Answer (score 0):

You can set following rule in your .htaccess to redirect s1.example.com to https://example.com

```
# subdomain to https

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)\?s1\.example\.com$ [NC]

RewriteRule ^ https://example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]
```

Comment: sir we not need to redirect our sub domain to main domain. we say our sub domain work perfectly on http but when we enter https in sub domain its show domain same not redirect but show main page data. we want something on our sub domain configuration . if we add https on sub domain our sub domain data show like on when simple show on http.